# Error in getting json data via POST ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending two values to another php via ajax and trying to get back two values and display one in a dropbox, and another in a input box. 
This is the ajax code:

```
function searchq6(){ 
var searchstate = $("input[name='region']").val(); 
var searchTxt = $("input[name='suburb']").val(); 
$.ajax({ 
url: 'search-suburb.php', 
type: 'POST', 
dataType: 'JSON', 
data: { 
  searchVal: searchTxt, 
  st:searchstate}, 
}) 
.done(function(response) { 
  var response = JSON.parse(response); 
  console.log(response);
}) 
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
  console.log(errorThrown);
}); 
}
```

And this is what I'm sending back from the php file:

```
$output = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
$searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
$st = $_POST['st'];
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations` WHERE state='".$st."'  AND `title` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' LIMIT 10")or     die("Could not search!");
if (!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = '<option>No results!</option>';
}else{
    $suburb = array();
    $postcode = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $suburb[] = $row['title'];
    $postcode[] = $row['title'];
    //echo $suburb;

} // while
    $result = ['success'=> true, 'data'=> ['suburb'=> $suburb, 'postcode' => $postcode], 'error' => null];
    echo json_encode($result);
} // else
} // main if
```

HTML:

```
Suburb:* <input type="text" name="suburb" list="sbb" required size="30" value="<?php echo $suburb;  ?>" onkeyup="searchq6()" id="output">
    <datalist id="sbb" name="taskoption6" >
            <option> </option>
    </datalist>
Postcode:* <input type="number" name="postcode" required value="<?php echo $postcode;  ?>"  id="postcode">
```

I'm getting this error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token E
at Object.parse (native)
at m.parseJSON (http://site/js/jquery.min.js:5:15998)
at Pb (http://site/js/jquery.min.js:5:18379)
at x (http://site/js/jquery.min.js:5:21793)
at XMLHttpRequest.send.b (http://site/js/jquery.min.js:5:26030)
```

Comment: you set the dataType so no need to parse this `var response = JSON.parse(response); `

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'search-suburb.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',//result is set to json
        data: {
            searchVal: searchTxt,
            st: searchstate
        },
    })
    .done(function(response) {//response parsed already
        var response = JSON.parse(response);//no need to parse here
        console.log(response);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

You set the `dataType:'json'` so no need to parse

`var response = JSON.parse(response); 
  console.log(response);`

You can have this `console.log(response);` directly without `var response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: `echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` can you do like this is in php also just to be sure can you `json_enode` this line `echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "Error description: {"success":true,"data":{"suburb…ER","DONCASTER EAST","CAMBERWELL"]},"error":null}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: did json_encode the the echo line from this `if (!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
}` this is probobly the echo you are getting but it is not `json_encode`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111068/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-guradio).